# spinner dropdown coming in the middle of the screen with android 2.3

Tags: android-spinner

I am trying following with android 2.3 as well as andorid 4.0.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/myColor"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<Spinner 
            android:id="@+id/spinnerControl"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" 
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
            android:divider="#000000"         
    android:dividerHeight="1dp" 
    style="@style/Sherlock.__Widget.Holo.Spinner"
            />
</LinearLayout>
```

The style xml file is -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="Sherlock.__Widget.Holo.Spinner" parent="@android:style/Widget">              
<item name="android:dropDownVerticalOffset">0dip</item>     
<item name="android:dropDownHorizontalOffset">0dip</item>     
<item name="android:dropDownWidth">wrap_content</item>     
<item name="android:gravity">left|center_vertical</item>     
<item name="android:spinnerMode">dropdown</item>     
<item name="android:clickable">true</item> 
</style> 
</resources>
```

With android 4.0, I am getting spinner dropdown, right under the spinner control. But with andorid 2.3, it is coming in the middle of the screen, I don't know why. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

To be precise, it was a new theme added to 4.0 by android.  To get this style you need to provide the theme called "holo". But unfortunately it is not available for 2.X devices. And so you will not be able to get such a drop down in 2.X.